# nginx - ubuntu 8.04 LTS - php-fpm

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-8.04

Does anyone know a repository which can be used to install php5-fpm for Ubuntu 8.04 LTS ? Can it be installed onto 8.04 LTS ?

Im currently usnig spwan-fcgi, but wanted to try php5-fpm to see the speed diference.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no such ppa in launchpad.
So, maybe the only choice is compile it by yourself.
:(